# Connect to the SQL instance using VB 6.0

Tags: sql, vb6, smo

How I can connect to the SQL instance using SMO with VB6.0?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can because Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll is not an ActiveX DLL, but depending on what it is you want to do you may be able to accomplish it using SQLDMO. Unfortunately Microsoft is ending support for SQLDMO after SQL 2008. You can read more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141187%28SQL.100%29.aspx